# How to update database entries in Spring Boot based on time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a subscription-model application that upon startup checks whether the record is expired or not (based on the current date) and eventually updates the "enabled" `boolean` value.

The Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDate expiry_date;

    @NotNull
    private boolean enabled;

    //Constructor, getter, setters
}
```

Inside the UserService class I implemented the following method:

```
//Disable records if past expiration Date
public void updateRecordsBasedOnTime(){
    List<User> orgs = (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

    for (User usr: users) {
        if(today.isAfter(org.getExpiry_date())){
            org.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the question is, where would be appropriate calling this method? At first I though inside the `@Controller` class, since an instance of the userRepository is already used, but the following method doesn't work:

```
@PostLoad
private void updateStatus() {
    userService.updateRecordsBasedOnTime();
}
```

Alternatively I though about implementing a cron method that would run though the records once every 12h:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */12 * * *")
    public static void updateDatabase() {
}
```

but even if I manage to successfully implement this method, I won't have the data updated at startup. Could anyone shed some light on this and maybe provide me with a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use triggers. With the help of triggers, you can not only execute tasks on startup but also at a periodic interval. you can read more about that and what suits your particular need.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html